# Issue with handling variables in threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, mutex, reloaddata

I am developing an application for showing the filesystem contents . I have two types of displays

1)OutlineView

2)IKImagebrowserView

The user can switch between the views . I am maintaining  the current view object in a global variable `currentview` as multiple controllers need to access it.

Now whenever the user switches views, one controller (running on a thread) changes this global  variable. However I have another controller which (depending on some DB operation) continuously refreshes the currentview using

```
[currentview reloadData];
```

Now whenever I switch rapidly between the views, there is an issue with the currentviewobject among these threads and the application crashes.
The crash report shows that the aplication crashes on the line

```
[currentview reloadData];
```

Is there any solution for this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
@synchronized(self)
{
   [currentview reloadData];
}
```

this will make a exclusive lock which will prevent it from being accessed by other threads simultaneously.

Comment: if the method is in thread which has this statement then it should be (self) otherwise (currentview)

Comment: seems to be working . I will again knock on your door if something happens :-)